# Add Row in Table without affecting conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code which works fine, however it messes up conditional formatting in my table. Is there a way to insert a new row in table via VBA without affecting conditional formatting?

```
Public Sub insertRowBelow()
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please specify *"it messes up conditional formatting"*? Screenshots might help a lot here. Also are you talking about a regular *worksheet* or  a *formatted table* (ListObject) within a worksheet.

Comment: I am talking about a listobject... The problem is that existing conditional formatting rules are split into two ranges at the insertion point

Comment: I recommend to read the [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) and add a new row only in the ListObject Table and not in the entire sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the row only within the `ListObject` not within the whole sheet (see [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables))

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRowInListObject()
    Dim ActTable As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if ActiveCell is not in a table
        Set ActTable = ActiveCell.ListObject
    On Error GoTo 0 're-activate error reporting!

    If Not ActTable Is Nothing Then 'only add row if ActiveCell is within a table
        ActTable.ListRows.Add ActiveCell.Row - ActTable.Range.Row
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that there are 2 differnt row counting systems:

1. `ActiveCell.Row` which returns the absolute row number of the worksheet
2. `ListRows.Add` which awaits the row number relatively to the beginning of the `ListObject`

So for example if the `ListObject` starts in row `5` of the worksheet then row number `1` of the `ListObject` is row number `5` of the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

This Will Work:

```
Public Sub insertRowBelow()

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Clear
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'Change Sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

        If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            'Change table name if needed - Insert one row above active cell
            .ListRows.Add ((ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Row))
            'Change table name if needed - Insert one row below active cell
            .ListRows.Add ((ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Row + 1))
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Error1004 note that if the ListObject does *not* start in row 1 of the table then `ActiveCell.Row` will point to the wrong row. I would use something like `ActiveCell.ListObject.ListRows.Add (ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.Row)` which is totally independend from the name of the ListObject. You just need to catch the error in case `ActiveCell` is not within a ListObject. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478896/3219613)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are perfectly right. See the edited version

Comment: @Error1004 That was not what I meant. `ActiveCell.Row` will return the row number **absolutely** to the worksheet. While `ListRows.Add` references to the row number **relative** to the beginning of the ListObject. Eg ListObject row 1 can be worksheet row 10 for example. These are two different row counting systems here. So you need to subtract the beginning of the ListObject. See my answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i get the point and i try to modify the code. Could you please evaluate?